# Can't get FormData object to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make an MVC-application with asp-net. In this application I want to be able to upload a file to the server. This worked with a simple `input type='file'` button but then I tried to make it look better and followed [this](https://github.com/adispartadev/spartan-multi-image-picker) tutorial.

It worked for the most part except that the FormData object that gets pasted to the controller is empty instead of containing a image.

I have tried to make the Javascript file with the ajax function the same as the function that I had before but it still wouldn't work.

The HTML-code:

```
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Upload Image</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="coba"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3"></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div></div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript code, The files object does contains an image when it gets appended to the FormData object fdata :

```
function actionDirectUpload(settings, input, parent) {
  var index = $(input).data('spartanindexinput');
  var fdata = new FormData();
  var files = input.files;
  var additionalParam = settings.directUpload.additionalParam;
  $(parent).find('[data-spartanindexloader="' + index + '"]').css('display', 'flex');
  fdata.append('file', files[0]);

  if (typeof additionalParam != 'undefined') {
    $.each(additionalParam, function (key, value) {
      fdata.append(key, value);
    });
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: settings.directUpload.url,
    data: fdata,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      $(parent).find('[data-spartanindexloader="' + index + '"]').css('display', 'none');

      if (typeof settings.directUpload.success != 'undefined') {
        settings.directUpload.success(this, data, textStatus, jqXHR);
      }
      alert("succes!");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $(parent).find('[data-spartanindexloader="' + index + '"]').css('display', 'none');
      if (typeof settings.directUpload.error != 'undefined') {
        settings.directUpload.error(this, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

And this is the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(IList<IFormFile> files)
{
  foreach(IFormFile item in files) {
  string filename = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(item.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
  filename = this.EnsureFilename(filename);
  using (FileStream filestream = System.IO.File.Create(this.GetPath(filename)))
  {

  }
}

  return this.Content("Success");
}
```

The `alert('succes');` gets called but the files object in the controller is empty instead of containing an image object.

Comment: Where is the `actionDirectUpload()` function called?

Comment: In a function loadImage(), this function is called everytime a image is selected.